# hide and show charts in ssrs report

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have two charts in single report .Based on parameter value I want to show charts .Parameter @center have 4 values like A,B,C,D. If I select @center = A or @center = B chart1 has to display If I select @center = C or @center = D chart2 has to display in report. Both charts are little similar .I want to write an expression to hide and show these charts.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your chart and select Chart Properties. Click on the Visibility tab and then select Show or Hide Based on an Expression. Click the expression icon. On this screen you can write an expression to determine when to show the chart. You'll notice that in the Category menu there is a section for Parameters. You can find your reports parameters here and add them to your expression. Sample expression for chart 1:

```
 =iif(Parameters!center.Value = A or Parameters!center.Value = B, False, True)
```

Comment: No problem. If this answer works for your purposes, consider marking it the correct answer so that future readers will know what to do.